# Uso de ? al utlizar una hoja de estilos en cascada externa

Tags: html

¿Porque se utiliza un '?' seguido de alguna información?, supongo que 'v' significa versión pero sin el es completamente igual la hoja de estilos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El símbolo `?` se utiliza para separar el nombre del archivo o ruta de los parámetros que se envían en la solicitud.

En el caso de las solicitudes web, el webserver tiene configurado un tiempo de vida para el caché de los sitios, incluyendo recursos como JS y CSS. Esto significa que, si la URL es la misma, el navegador puede usar una versión del documento que tiene en sus archivos temporales, o en el caché de la sesión activa, sin necesidad de descargar nuevamente el recurso. Se utiliza un número de versión para obligar al navegador a descargar una nueva versión del recurso cuando se modifique el número de versión. Esto puede ser porque la aplicación se encuentra en desarrollo, o porque se hicieron cambios al recurso y se requiere limpiar el caché del cliente.

[image: Al incluir el número de versión, se especifica una forma de "identificación" del recurso que se está descargando.]

Si fuésemos a cambiar el número de versión de los recursos CSS de esta ´página, forzaríamos al navegador a volver a descargar el recurso, y así forzamos a todos los clientes a ver los cambios reflejados en sus navegadores.

Es una forma de "truquear" la URL a nuestro favor.